# MySQL - Display months dynamically according to user input

Tags: php, mysql

I am not sure how I am going to do this. I'm on my wit's end and exhausted all the resources I have right now.

Alright, I have one database with column, monthname, fiscal_year, and amount.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `savings`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `savings` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `monthname` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `fiscal_year` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(30,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `net_savings_id_unique` (`id`,`account_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=841 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

And here's the content:

```
LOCK TABLES `savings` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `net_savings` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `net_savings` VALUES (1,1,'January','2016',-1291.47,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-23 06:45:00'),(2,1,'February','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(3,1,'March','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(4,1,'April','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(5,1,'May','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(6,1,'June','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(7,1,'July','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(8,1,'August','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(9,1,'September','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(10,1,'October','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(11,1,'November','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(12,1,'December','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(13,1,'January','2017',389296.02,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-23 06:45:00'),(14,1,'February','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(15,1,'March','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(16,1,'April','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(17,1,'May','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(18,1,'June','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(19,1,'July','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(20,1,'August','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(21,1,'September','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(22,1,'October','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(23,1,'November','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(24,1,'December','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(25,1,'January','2018',216143.70,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(26,1,'February','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(27,1,'March','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(28,1,'April','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(29,1,'May','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(30,1,'June','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(31,1,'July','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(32,1,'August','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(33,1,'September','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(34,1,'October','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(35,1,'November','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(36,1,'December','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(37,1,'January','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(38,1,'February','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(39,1,'March','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(40,1,'April','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(41,1,'May','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(42,1,'June','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(43,1,'July','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(44,1,'August','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(45,1,'September','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(46,1,'October','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(47,1,'November','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(48,1,'December','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(49,1,'January','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(50,1,'February','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(51,1,'March','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(52,1,'April','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(53,1,'May','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(54,1,'June','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(55,1,'July','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(56,1,'August','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(57,1,'September','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(58,1,'October','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(59,1,'November','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(60,1,'December','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:45:00','2016-09-28 02:36:34'),(61,2,'January','2016',53840.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(62,2,'February','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(63,2,'March','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(64,2,'April','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(65,2,'May','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(66,2,'June','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(67,2,'July','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(68,2,'August','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(69,2,'September','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(70,2,'October','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(71,2,'November','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(72,2,'December','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(73,2,'January','2017',1669693.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(74,2,'February','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(75,2,'March','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(76,2,'April','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(77,2,'May','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(78,2,'June','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(79,2,'July','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(80,2,'August','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(81,2,'September','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(82,2,'October','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(83,2,'November','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(84,2,'December','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(85,2,'January','2018',1980328.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(86,2,'February','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(87,2,'March','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(88,2,'April','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(89,2,'May','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(90,2,'June','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(91,2,'July','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(92,2,'August','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(93,2,'September','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(94,2,'October','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(95,2,'November','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(96,2,'December','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(97,2,'January','2019',2428559.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(98,2,'February','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(99,2,'March','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(100,2,'April','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(101,2,'May','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(102,2,'June','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(103,2,'July','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(104,2,'August','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(105,2,'September','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(106,2,'October','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(107,2,'November','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(108,2,'December','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(109,2,'January','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(110,2,'February','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(111,2,'March','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(112,2,'April','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(113,2,'May','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(114,2,'June','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(115,2,'July','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(116,2,'August','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(117,2,'September','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(118,2,'October','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(119,2,'November','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(120,2,'December','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 06:57:19','2016-09-23 07:27:11'),(181,4,'January','2016',963.32,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-23 07:11:42'),(182,4,'February','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(183,4,'March','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(184,4,'April','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(185,4,'May','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(186,4,'June','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(187,4,'July','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(188,4,'August','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(189,4,'September','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(190,4,'October','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(191,4,'November','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(192,4,'December','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(193,4,'January','2017',3960.93,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-23 07:11:42'),(194,4,'February','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(195,4,'March','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(196,4,'April','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(197,4,'May','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(198,4,'June','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(199,4,'July','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(200,4,'August','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(201,4,'September','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(202,4,'October','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(203,4,'November','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(204,4,'December','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(205,4,'January','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(206,4,'February','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(207,4,'March','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(208,4,'April','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(209,4,'May','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(210,4,'June','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(211,4,'July','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(212,4,'August','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(213,4,'September','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(214,4,'October','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(215,4,'November','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(216,4,'December','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(217,4,'January','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(218,4,'February','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(219,4,'March','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(220,4,'April','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(221,4,'May','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(222,4,'June','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(223,4,'July','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(224,4,'August','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(225,4,'September','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(226,4,'October','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(227,4,'November','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(228,4,'December','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(229,4,'January','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(230,4,'February','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(231,4,'March','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(232,4,'April','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(233,4,'May','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(234,4,'June','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(235,4,'July','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(236,4,'August','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(237,4,'September','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(238,4,'October','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(239,4,'November','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(240,4,'December','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:11:42','2016-09-26 03:02:14'),(241,5,'January','2016',-261.74,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(242,5,'February','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(243,5,'March','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(244,5,'April','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(245,5,'May','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(246,5,'June','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(247,5,'July','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(248,5,'August','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(249,5,'September','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(250,5,'October','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(251,5,'November','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(252,5,'December','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(253,5,'January','2017',24160.80,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(254,5,'February','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(255,5,'March','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(256,5,'April','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(257,5,'May','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(258,5,'June','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(259,5,'July','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(260,5,'August','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(261,5,'September','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(262,5,'October','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(263,5,'November','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(264,5,'December','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(265,5,'January','2018',24160.80,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(266,5,'February','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(267,5,'March','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(268,5,'April','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(269,5,'May','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(270,5,'June','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(271,5,'July','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(272,5,'August','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(273,5,'September','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(274,5,'October','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(275,5,'November','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(276,5,'December','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(277,5,'January','2019',8053.60,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(278,5,'February','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(279,5,'March','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(280,5,'April','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(281,5,'May','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(282,5,'June','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(283,5,'July','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(284,5,'August','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(285,5,'September','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(286,5,'October','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(287,5,'November','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(288,5,'December','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(289,5,'January','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(290,5,'February','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(291,5,'March','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(292,5,'April','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(293,5,'May','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(294,5,'June','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(295,5,'July','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(296,5,'August','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(297,5,'September','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(298,5,'October','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(299,5,'November','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(300,5,'December','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:20:36','2016-09-23 07:20:36'),(301,6,'January','2016',8846.54,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(302,6,'February','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(303,6,'March','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(304,6,'April','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(305,6,'May','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(306,6,'June','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(307,6,'July','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(308,6,'August','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(309,6,'September','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(310,6,'October','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(311,6,'November','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(312,6,'December','2016',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(313,6,'January','2017',41141.34,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(314,6,'February','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(315,6,'March','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(316,6,'April','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(317,6,'May','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(318,6,'June','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(319,6,'July','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(320,6,'August','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(321,6,'September','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(322,6,'October','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(323,6,'November','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(324,6,'December','2017',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(325,6,'January','2018',41141.34,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(326,6,'February','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(327,6,'March','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(328,6,'April','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(329,6,'May','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(330,6,'June','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(331,6,'July','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(332,6,'August','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(333,6,'September','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(334,6,'October','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(335,6,'November','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(336,6,'December','2018',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(337,6,'January','2019',41141.34,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(338,6,'February','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(339,6,'March','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(340,6,'April','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(341,6,'May','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(342,6,'June','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(343,6,'July','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(344,6,'August','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(345,6,'September','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(346,6,'October','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(347,6,'November','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(348,6,'December','2019',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(349,6,'January','2020',27427.56,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(350,6,'February','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(351,6,'March','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(352,6,'April','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(353,6,'May','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(354,6,'June','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(355,6,'July','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(356,6,'August','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(357,6,'September','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(358,6,'October','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(359,6,'November','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11'),(360,6,'December','2020',0.00,'2016-09-23 07:34:11','2016-09-23 07:34:11');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `net_savings` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

As you can see, this is pretty much getting more complicated for me as the user, wanted to input four values.

**From:** Month and Fiscal Year

**To:** Month and Fiscal Year

Now If I were the user, I would like to input June 2016 and March 2017. My result set will be displaying:

June, July, August, Sept, October, November, December(2016), January, February, March (2017)

So this is going to be very dynamic, and I only have two columns to use and both of them are storing strings.

This is my current code and I stucked here.

```
select a.id, a.account, a.region, sum(n.amount) as 'TotalNet',
  sum(case when n.monthname = "November" then n.amount else 0 end) as `Nov`,
  sum(case when n.monthname = "December" then n.amount else 0 end) as `Dec`,
  sum(case when n.monthname = "January" then n.amount else 0 end) as `Jan`,
  sum(case when n.monthname = "February" then n.amount else 0 end) as `Feb`,
  sum(case when n.monthname = "March" then n.amount else 0 end) as `Mar`,
  sum(case when n.monthname = "April" then n.amount else 0 end) as `Apr`,
  sum(case when n.monthname = "May" then n.amount else 0 end) as `May`,
  sum(case when n.monthname = "June" then n.amount else 0 end) as `Jun`,
  sum(case when n.monthname = "July" then n.amount else 0 end) as `Jul`,
  sum(case when n.monthname = "August" then n.amount else 0 end) as `Aug`,
  sum(case when n.monthname = "September" then n.amount else 0 end) as `Sep`,
  sum(case when n.monthname = "October" then n.amount else 0 end) as `Oct`
from 
savings n left outer join accounts a
on a.id = n.account_id
where fiscal_year = 2016
group by a.account
order by a.account desc;
```

Please help sql experts! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nice idea putting some data in for us to test an answer against. But you have a Create for `savings` and an INSERT for `net_savings` Can we assume a typo?

Comment: I think, what you need is a separate table say 'Calender' to deal with it. That could be the best dynamic solution. Finally convert strings to DateTime for the year or month.

Comment: And no `accounts` table?

Comment: please disregard the accounts table, I can eventually join it later on as only name can be seen there.

Comment: @AT-2016 can you show us how? please.

Comment: It's totally a weird and huge thing. Do some research as this will differ that I'll be giving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### General

You cannot dynamically generate columns. So in the MySQL only solution we focus on creating rows. On the PHP solution we are doing the transposition in PHP.

### PHP Approach

#### Idea

Let us query our table row by row. Then transpose it. We also generate an entry for every month between `start` and `end` in order to always have an entry.

#### Implementation

```
SELECT a.account_id, fiscal_year, monthname, SUM(n.amount) as ThisMonth
FROM  savings n
LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts a
     ON .....
WHERE fiscal_year >= YEAR($start_date)
     AND monthname >= MONTHNAME($start_date)
     AND fiscal_year <= YEAR($end_date)
     AND monthname <= MONTHNAME($end_date)
GROUP BY c.date;
```

where we generate

```
$start_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('%M %Y', $input_start);
$end_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('%M %Y', $input_end);
$interval = DateInverall:createFromDateString('1 month');
```

Now let's transpose it, from rows to columns:

```
// QUERY OUR MYSQL USING PREPARED STATEMENTS
$dates = [];
for ($date = $start_date; $date <= $end_date; $date->add($interval)) {
   $dates[] = $date;
}

$accounts = [];
foreach($rows as $row) {
    if (!isset($accounts[$row['account_id']])) {
        $entry = []
        $accounts[$row['account_id']] = $entry;
    }
    $fyear = $row['fiscal_year'];
    $month = $row['monthname'];
    $accounts[$row['account_id']][$fyear][$month] = $row['TotalMonth'];
}

//print header. We are doing this very stupid here ,
//you want some sort of table layout
echo "Account ID";
foreach($dates as $date) {
    echo $date;
}
echo "\n";
// output our data
// at this point accounts is a multidimensional array: 
foreach($account as $aid => $account) {
   echo $aid;
   foreach($dates as $date) {
      $value = 0;
      if (!isset($account[$date->format('%Y')][$date->format('%M')])) {
         $value = $account[$date->format('%Y')][$date->format('%M')];
      }
      echo $value;
   }
   echo "\n";
}
```

### MySQL only (per-row) approach

#### The idea

This solution focuses on per-row solution. Transposition can be done in PHP afterwards.

I assume we want to generate every month no matter if there is an entry in `savings` or not.

In order for any select statement to succeed we need a table to select from. While we can generate arbitrary values for every entry, we still need entries available.

In our case the easiest is to generate a table with dates.

#### The calendar table

Let's generate a table that contains entries from 1900 to 2100:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE gen_cal()
  BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE `calendar` (`date` DATE NOT NULL);
    SET @start = MAKEDATE(1900, 1);
    WHILE @start <= MAKEDATE(2100, 1) DO
      INSERT INTO `calendar` (`date`) VALUES (@start);
      SET @start = ADDDATE(@start, interval 1 month);
    END WHILE;
  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Let's generate it using `CALL`. It generates a table with 2401 entries.

```
CALL gen_cal();
```

#### The select

Let's use our brand new `calendar` table to select (I removed the `account` part for simplicity).

```
SELECT c.date, MONTHNAME(c.date) as month, SUM(n.amount) as ThisMonth
FROM calendar c
LEFT OUTER JOIN savings n
   ON fiscal_year = YEAR(c.date)
     AND monthname = MONTHNAME(c.date)
WHERE c.date
   BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('1 March 2016', '%d %M %Y')
   AND STR_TO_DATE('1 March 2017', '%d %M %Y')
GROUP BY c.date;
```

Note the part `STR_TO_DATE('1 % %', '%d %M %Y')` where we convert the format "1 
March 2017" to a date. I assume that you can fill in '1 % %' via a prepared statement with the user given data.

The usage of `YEAR` and `MONTHNAME` makes it possible to select the correct date which we can then easily use to match against our user given input.

The usage of `LEFT OUTER JOIN` ensures we generate an entry for EVERY month, no matter if we have an entry in `savings` or not.

#### Drawbacks

We cannot in MySQL generate columns dynamically. So we are restricted to rows.